# Return function on a external php file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying do develop a simple log in form in order to learn php.

I've created the form and a function which send a query to a mysql database to retrieve username and password (stored in md5 encryption) and control it with data inserted by the user.

The problem is that this function (login() )is in a external file called fun_login.php and when I call it from the page login.php it opens the page fun_login.php and it doesn't come back to login.php (I think because there is some problem with the return value)

In login.php I've included the file fun_login.php with

```
<?php

include "fun_login.php";

?>
```

**login.php**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-5">
            <form action="fun_login.php" role="form" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nome">Username:</label>
                    <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submitlogin" name="submitlogin">Log In</button>
            </form>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submitlogin'])) {
                $control = login($_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']));
            if($control) header("Location: ./index.php");
            else header("Location: ./login.php");
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**fun_login.php**

```
    <?php

function login($username, $password) {
    $myconn = mysql_connect(localhost, root, password);
    mysql_select_db('portfolio', $myconn);
    $query = "SELECT username,password,admin FROM utenti WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" .$password . "';";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $myconn)or die('Error, insert query failed');  
        // conto il numero di occorrenze trovate nel db
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

// se il database è vuoto lo stampo a video
if ($numrows == 0) return false;
// se invece trovo delle occorrenze...
else return true;   
}
?>
```

Comment: MD5 is ***not*** "encryption"; it's a *hash*. It's also entirely inadequate to protect passwords; use a *modern secure hash* like bcrypt, best in the form of PHP's built in [`password_hash`](http://php.net/password_hash).

Comment: and dont use mysql either.. its terrible and bad and dangerous and deprecated.

Comment: `$myconn = mysql_connect(localhost, root, password);` are the constants `localhost`, `root` and `password` defined anywhere?

Comment: `die('Error, insert query failed');` Your query is a select query, not an insert

Comment: also, your `header()` calls are after html is outputed, so youll get a 'headers already sent' error.

Comment: @DevDonkey what should I use instead?

Comment: @MarkBaker I pasted it from another file. This isn't a problem.

Comment: @DevDonkey I've tried to remove header() but the problem remains

Comment: You should be using MySQLi or PDO instead

Comment: @MarkBaker ok thanks u, I'll take a look!  I didn't defined localhost ecc. anywhere, when I used error_reporting(ALL) some errors about that thing have been displayed, now I resolved them! The problem was the <form action="fun_login.php">

Answer (score 0):

At the time you're calling

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitlogin'])) {
    $control = login($_POST['username'], md5($_POST['password']));
if($control) header("Location: ./index.php");
else header("Location: ./login.php");
    }
?>
```

in your `login.php` the headers have been already sent so `header('Location:')` won't work.

You need to put that before any output (echo or html) gets displayed.
If you look in the error log you'll probably see `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`

By the looks of it that file is included in a layout or something so your `login()` call has to be even before that.

Answer (score -2):

What's the error message you are receiving?
use this command at the beginning of your php files:

```
// Report all PHP errors 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then you will know which error has occurred, if at all.

Comment: This is not an answer, please don't post it as one. This is a comment at best. Since you do not have enough reputation to post comments yet, you better refrain from such commentary entirely until you can. Being downvoted for non-answers isn't conducive to that goal.

Comment: @deceze, my tough also, but then I've seen his reputation... He/she cannot still comment so, we should forgive him/her :D